# Can I return html from a classic asp vbscript asp function? What about PHP?

Tags: php, function, vbscript, asp-classic

Can I call a Classic ASP vbscript function and have it return html?  I have a function that does some calculations, but I want it to send back the html as well.  Will it do that? .

```
response.write MyFunction()
function myFunction()
  return "<b>test</b>"
end function
```

I get a type mismatch error.

Second question, please, If this were php, can I send back html and do something like echo MyPHPFunction()?

I didn't know if php was different than asp/vbscript on this.  It seems you can send just about anything around in php.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In vb script, assign the return value to the function name; something like this:

```
function myFunction()
    myFunction = "<b>test</b>"
end function
```

Answer (score 4):

ASP:

```
<%
Function MyFunction()
  MyFunction = "<b>test</b>"
End Function

Response.Write MyFunction()
%>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
function MyPHPFunction() {
  return "<b>test</b>";
}

echo MyPHPFunction();
?>
```

ASP with a parameter:

```
<%
Function MyFunction2(inStr)
  MyFunction2 = "<b>" & Server.HTMLEncode(inStr) & "</b>"
End Function

Response.Write MyFunction2("foo & bar")
%>
```

PHP with a parameter:

```
<?php
function MyPHPFunction2($inStr) {
  return "<b>" . htmlentites($inStr). "</b>";
}

echo MyPHPFunction2("foo & bar");
?>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I would have put the check but the other guy was first.

Comment: @johnny You should mark the best answer as accepted, not the first one :) And this one is a good bit more detailed than the other ;)

Comment: The first one was what I needed and it was first so I marked it.

Answer (score 1):

You could have

```
<?php    
function printHelloWorld(){
     echo 'hello world';
}
function getHelloWorld(){
     return 'hello world';
}

printHelloWorld();
//output: hello world
echo getHelloWorld();
//output: hello world
?>
```